# How to retrieve values from database based on Name using flask

Tags: python, mysql

I am doing a project in python .I have an HTML in that I have two select one to select State and one to select Name and I have a filter button when I click the button corresponding action was happened in python.I have a database "bucketlist" in that I have Name,Password,State colums based on selected state and Name I should display the table.I had done one state and one Table if I select multiple it is not working it consider only the first select one.please help me.

Here is my Code:

sample.Html:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/admin" method="post">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="tohrlable">State:</label>
                        <select name="text1[]" class="selectpicker" data-size="5" multiple  data-live-search="true" data-selected-text-format="count > 2">
                            <option value="All"selected>All</option>
                            <option value="tamilnadu">tamilnadu</option>
                            <option value="Andhara">Andhara</option>
                            <option value="Keraal">Kerala</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="tohrlable">Name:</label>
                        <select name="text2[]" class="selectpicker" data-size="5" multiple  data-live-search="true" data-selected-text-format="count > 2">
                            <option selected>All</option>
                            <option value="preethi">preethi</option>
                            <option value="saranya">saranya</option>
                            <option value="Tharini">Tharini</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
                    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="background:#2196f3">
                      Filter
                    </button>
                </form>
```

py:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("sample.html")

@app.route('/admin',methods=['POST','GET'])
def hello():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        a = request.form.getlist('text1[]')
        b = ' '.join(a)
        c = request.form.getlist('text2[]')
        d = ' '.join(c)
        print d
        Name = d
        cursor.execute("select Name from user_master WHERE Name='" + Name + "'")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        return jsonify({"data": data})
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try `IN` query:

```
Name = "'" + "','".join(d) + "'"
cursor.execute("select Name from user_master WHERE Name IN (" + Name + ")"
```

Comment: when I return it in Jsonify it returns nothing. can we use for loop ?

Comment: Thank you sir !..It is now working how can we select state and Name ?

Comment: How can we retrieve the full table based on State and Name Column?

Comment: for multiple states and names ? can you provide a sample set of state and names?

Comment: like wise name I want to retrieve State column also

Comment: I want to retrieve tables based on State and Name selected(mutliple select)

Comment: In the select query I am selecting only Name column like that I want to select State column also

Comment: sir,your emailId please

Comment: State = "'" + "','".join(a) + "'"
        Name = "'" + "','".join(c) + "'"
        cursor.execute("select Sno,Name,State,MailId,UserName,Password from user_master WHERE  Status='" + State + "',Name='" + Name + "'") Is this correct for select a table based on State and Name column